# JavaScript not executed from Objective C

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode5

So I have a WebView that captures changes in URL in a website to open the camera.
Once the picture is done, I want to send it back with:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"addImageiOS(%@)", base64EncodedImage]];
```

It does not work, and my guess is because self.webView is not the webview.
I'm a mess with this delegates and things, I'm used to Android.
Well, my code is here.

WebViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *ToolBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *MenuButton;

@end
```

WebViewController.m

```
#import "WebViewController.h"
@interface WebViewController ()
@end
@implementation WebViewController
@synthesize webView = _webView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
NSString *js_result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.location.href"];
NSLog(@"%@", js_result);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

_webView.delegate = self;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://some_url"];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:requestURL];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *URL= [prefs stringForKey:@"URL"];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSURL *url = request.URL;
NSString *filePath= [url path];
//NSString *myString = [url absoluteString];
if ([filePath rangeOfString:@"TAKEPICWITHCAMERA"].location != NSNotFound) {
    //TAKE PIC WITH CAMERA
    [self openCamera];
    return NO;


}

return YES;
}

- (void)openCamera {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

#pragma mark - Image Picker Controller delegate methods

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
NSString *base64EncodedImage = [self encodeToBase64String:chosenImage];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"addImageiOS(%@)", base64EncodedImage]];
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
- (NSString *)encodeToBase64String:(UIImage *)image {
return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}

@end
```

It must be some small thing I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be just missing quotes in your JavaScript Call :

```
@"addImageiOS(\"%@\")"
```